# .net Core Webpack Publish from VS 2017 failing

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to publish a .net Core Angular 4 project from Visual Studio to Azure. During the publish, I get the following error:

```
    ERROR in ./$$_gendir/~/angular-tree-component/dist/components/tree.component.ngfactory.ts
Module parse failed: C:\projects\DataFinch\Pinnacle\DataFinch.Pinnacle.Web\$$_gendir\node_modules\angular-tree-component\dist\components\tree.component.ngfactory.ts Unexpected token (21:26)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import * as i10 from 'angular-tree-component/dist/components/tree.component';
| import * as i11 from 'angular-tree-component/dist/models/tree-dragged-element.model';
| const styles_TreeComponent:any[] = ([] as any[]);
| export const RenderType_TreeComponent:i0.RendererType2 = i0.╔╡crt({encapsulation:2,
|     styles:styles_TreeComponent,data:{}});
 @ ./$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/components/settings/positions/positionsList.component.ngfactory.ts 11:0-127
 @ ./$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.module.browser.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts
```

Everything works fine on my local machine, I just cant seem to publish when env is set to prod:

**Update:**
Here is my [Webpack.js](https://gist.github.com/chriskooken/afb8785278270e35a38a51f785b9f536) file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your webpack file contains an appropriate module rule:

```
{ test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/, include: [/ClientApp/, /\$\$_gendir/], use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack' },
```

You can have a look at [my webpack.config.js](https://gist.github.com/dasMulli/59596f91de3f139a99931840ba6d4a8a) which is the default asp.net core spa angular 4 template updated for angular 5 (until the version of the spa services supporting the angular CLI is released)

Comment: I replaced my line with this one and I'm still getting the same error. I have included my webpack.js file above.

Comment: yea, didn't think i needed the _gendir stuff. But I did. When I put that back in, everything worked. Thanks!