# .net Core Angular 4 Webpack Publish from VS 2017 failing

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, .net-core

I am trying to publish a .net Core Angular 4 project from Visual Studio to Azure.

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067167/net-core-webpack-publish-from-vs-2017-failing) weeks ago, and was able to get past it. Everything was working fine, but I recently added Kendo controls to my project and now, once again, I can not publish

During the publish, I get the following error:

```
    Child
    Hash: aa44435c6a38edcdbf9a
    Time: 11544ms
             Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    main-client.js  268 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main-client

    ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not resolve @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs relative to C:/projects/Apps/myApp/DTS.myApp.Web/ClientApp/app/app.module.shared.ts., resolving symbol AppModuleShared in C:/projects/Apps/myApp/DTS.myApp.Web/ClientApp/app/app.module.shared.ts, resolving symbol AppModuleShared in C:/projects/Apps/myApp/DTS.myApp.Web/ClientApp/app/app.module.shared.ts

    ERROR in ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts
Module not found(0,0): Error : Can't resolve './../$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.module.browser.ngfactory' in 'C:\projects\DataFinch\myApp\DTS.myApp.Web\ClientApp'
     @ ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts 5:0-95
Child
    Hash: c18981f0ab297b0a26e0
    Time: 11492ms
             Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    main-server.js  1.8 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main-server

    ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not resolve @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs relative to C:/projects/Apps/myApp/DTS.myApp.Web/ClientApp/app/app.module.shared.ts., resolving symbol AppModuleShared in C:/projects/Apps/myApp/DTS.myApp.Web/ClientApp/app/app.module.shared.ts, resolving symbol AppModuleShared in C:/projects/Apps/myApp/DTS.myApp.Web/ClientApp/app/app.module.shared.ts

    ERROR in ./ClientApp/boot.server.ts
Module not found(0,0): Error : Can't resolve './../$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.module.server.ngfactory' in 'C:\projects\DataFinch\myApp\DTS.myApp.Web\ClientApp'
     @ ./ClientApp/boot.server.ts 8:0-94
C:\projects\DataFinch\myApp\DTS.myApp.Web\DTS.myApp.Web.csproj(105,5): Error MSB3073: The command "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod" exited with code 2.
```

Everything works fine on my local machine, I just cant seem to publish when env is set to prod:

Here is my [Webpack.js](https://gist.github.com/chriskooken/66a3970fc5a765a6b07f75ed9f09c639) file.

Here is my [package.json](https://gist.github.com/chriskooken/7f66a1254f04964dd5183378442edfe9) file

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see different in your webpack config file for development and production is the loader for typescript. Thus can you try using the same loader you're using during development for production? This is my theory, although rather inchoate, but it seems to me that ngtools isn't parsing your newly added third party component, and if it's building in development, then `awesome-ts-loader` and `angular2-template-loader` may be parsing it.

Comment: I am also unable to publish. But the error I am getting is `ERROR in main-client.js from UglifyJs
    Unexpected token: operator (>) [main-client.js:52912,19]` when I run the command in a terminal by itself.